# Switch DNS settings per Windows user?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, dns, opendns

I have set up an account at OpenDNS for web filtering. I think it is a great service and don't want to change to any alternative.

What I would like to do is *change the DNS settings per user* so I can choose who on that particular computer has filtered web access. What is the most reliable/robust solution to do this?

Windows XP Professional.

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: I am using xp pro

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at writing a script that uses the netsh command.
Example:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" <Primary DNS ADDRESS>
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" <Secondary DNS ADDRESS> index=2
```

You can leave the script on the desktop of any user that needs to change the dns information, you can also create a script that reverses the change and set that script to run at logout.

Comment: This is a "manual" solution - and it requires Admin rights too - so it will not work for web filtering, which @Rhythmic wants.

Comment: You can place these lines in the login script for each individual user or groups of users in OU's if he's using AD.

Comment: But isn't this per a machine like all other TCP/IP settings and not per users ?
This will probably will not work on a terminal server.